# xcuitrunner not starting - SocketException

Tags: windows, ios

I'm trying to launch xcuitrunner on my Windows machine, but I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it: [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:27015
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapShot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
  at System.Net.SOckets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
  at Quamotion.Devices.iOS.Managed.MuxerDeviceClient.Connect(Boolean forceTcp, String muxerHost, Int32 muxerPort)
  at Quamotion.Devices.iOS.Managed.MuxerDeviceClient.ListDevices(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<Main>b__2()
  at Microsoft.Extension.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

When I checked the processes associated with port 27015 via `netstat`, I found no process existing.

It looks like xcuitrunner is still looking for a port 27015.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 27015 is the port used by the Apple Mobile Device Service. This service manages the connectivity with iOS devices.
You can install the Apple Mobile Device Service by installing iTunes.

Can you check whether iTunes is installed, and the Apple Mobile Device Service is running?